# Java class design to support multi-valued options

Tags: java, class-design

The following are some of the codes:

```
ENJOY08A,
AUTO09B,
PLAY06D,
SUMMER08W,
WINTER03S,
LEAF02A,
```

Each of these values correspond to a specific area.
For example, `ENJOY08A` and `AUTO09B` correspond to `DEPT_A`

`PLAY06D` corresponds to `DEPT_B`

`SUMMER08W`, `WINTER03S` and `LEAF02A` corresponds to `DEPT_C`

There are a fixed number of areas (5 areas), but unlimited codes. A code will correspond to only one area, but an area can have any number of codes.

None of the above will be stored in the database.

I need to create a Java class which will support the following operations..
Given the code, I need to know the corresponding area.
Given the area, I need to know all the corresponding codes.

What's the best way to go about designing the Java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest method is to put the AREAS into a `<String, Set>` HashMap, then enter all  the associated CODES into the relevant map. Then, you can get the Set of all codes for an area or iterate over the sets to find which one contains the code you are searching for.

```
for (String k : (Set<String>)areas.keySet()) {
 if (areas.get(k).contains(theCode))
  return k;
}
return "NO CORRESPONDING AREA FOUND";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

I ended up creating a simple final singleton class with a 

private Map<Department, List<String>> deptCodeSet = new HashMap<Department, List<String>>(); 

and two methods 
List<String> getCodesForDept(Department dept) 
Department getDeptForCode(String code)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the guava [multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).  I believe it provides the functionality you want.

Comment: MultiMap is for mapping a key to a collection, so yes that is the solution I would pick up for this need.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of codes is unlimited, you need to come up with a rule for mapping codes into departments.  Probably it will be something like add up all the codes and take that sum modulo 5. There are an infinite number of choices for what this rule can be.

Something like

```
public class DepartmentCoder {

    public static String toCode(Department department) {
        // TODO: Randomly generate a string having the desired property, such
        // as the sum of the string's codepoint modulo the number of departments
        // equaling the ordinal value of the department.       
    }

    public static Department(String code) {
        // TODO: Do some math on the codepoints of the string
        return result % Deparatments.NUMBER_OF_DEPARTMENTS;
    }
}
```

I think, though, that the notion of "code" (as opposed to compression or encryption) is that the code values are fixed.  Any rule-based solution can be figured out more easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `MultiMap` (Google guava library), which is a bi-directional map, as a backend.
2. Fill the map using normal puts, either during construction time or from a properties file using the Java `Properties` class
3. Offer two interface methods: `regionForCode(String code)` and `codeForRegion(String region)` which use the BiMap to retrieve the mapped values.

You might even consider putting region into an `enum` instead of a simple `String`, because your region values are fixed. Then the domain would be described a little bit more consistently.

Edited: I noticed that BiMap is for unique mappings. The anser with MultiMap is correct, so I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class with two `Maps`.

The first is a `Map<String, Set<String>>` for looking up the set (alternatively `List`) of codes for a given area. Somebody also suggested Guava's `MultiMap`, that is essentially what this is.

The second would be a `Map<String, String>` for looking up the area of any given code.

Then just implement the appropriate `String findAreaForCode(String code)` and `Set<String> listCodesInArea(String area)` methods.

Finally, if the list of areas is small, finite and relatively static (doesn't need to grow dynamically at run-time) then I would consider using a Java `enum` in place of an  ordinary `String`.